# SELECT command doesn't work properly in Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create Stored procedure that selects specific rows after entering 2 values for parameters.

So my code is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `find_stock_order`(
    in product_name varchar(45),
        thedate date)
BEGIN
    SELECT * from stock_order_view 
    WHERE product_name=product_name AND DateTime_order = thedate;
END
```

I use WHERE .... AND .... to select needed rows. However, it show more rows than needed as if I used OR instead of AND. When I type in product_name 'Cola' and in thedate '2022-12-01', it shows all rows with 'Cola' with all possible dates and all rows with '2022-12-01' with all possible products.

How should I write a code so that it shows only rows where product_name='Cola' AND thedate='2022-12-01'

Comment: *"it show more rows than needed as if I used OR instead of AND"* - try running the query outside procedure.

Comment: it works correctly when I run it outside procedure: 
SELECT * from stock_order_view 
 WHERE product_name='Cola' AND DateTime_order = '2023-09-03';
However, I need it in my stored procedure

Comment: try renaming the parameters, use different name. specifically that `product_name`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the naming conflict between the parameters and the column names in your SQL query. When you use the same name for parameters as the column names in your query, MySQL is interpreting them as the same, and that's why you're getting results that don't match the specific values you're trying to filter.

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `find_stock_order`(
    in p_product_name varchar(45),
    in p_thedate date)
BEGIN
    SELECT * from stock_order_view 
    WHERE product_name = p_product_name AND DateTime_order = p_thedate;
END
```